# List of dictionaries - Function with list index is out of range

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through a variable of nested dictionaries (a JSON Google Maps output). The code below worked on a smaller output, but now it is returning an error.

The var geocode_result has a length of `28376`.

```
lat_long_list = []
def geocode_results_process(x):         
    for i in range(len(x)):
        list_component = x[i][0]['geometry']['location']
        for val in list_component:
            latitude = list_component['lat']
        for val in list_component:
            longitude = list_component['lng']
        latlong = str(latitude) + ',' + str(longitude)
        lat_long_list.append(latlong)

geocode_results_process(geocode_result)
```

The expected result is a string list of the latitude and longitude appended to the lat_long_list.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-18aa2be2eddd> in <module>
     13         lat_long_list.append(latlong)
     14 
---> 15 geocode_results_process(geocode_result)

<ipython-input-167-18aa2be2eddd> in geocode_results_process(x)
      5 def geocode_results_process(x):
      6     for i in range(len(x)):
----> 7         list_component = x[i][0]['geometry']['location']
      8         for val in list_component:
      9             latitude = list_component['lat']

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sample of geocode_result:

```
geocode_result[1]

[{'address_components': [{'long_name': '620',
    'short_name': '620',
    'types': ['street_number']},
   {'long_name': 'South Broadway',
    'short_name': 'S Broadway',
    'types': ['route']},
   {'long_name': 'Downtown Los Angeles',
    'short_name': 'Downtown Los Angeles',
    'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'Los Angeles',
    'short_name': 'Los Angeles',
    'types': ['locality', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'Los Angeles County',
    'short_name': 'Los Angeles County',
    'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'California',
    'short_name': 'CA',
    'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'United States',
    'short_name': 'US',
    'types': ['country', 'political']},
   {'long_name': '90014', 'short_name': '90014', 'types': ['postal_code']},
   {'long_name': '1807',
    'short_name': '1807',
    'types': ['postal_code_suffix']}],
  'formatted_address': '620 S Broadway, Los Angeles, CA 90014, USA',
  'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 34.0459956, 'lng': -118.2523297},
   'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
   'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 34.04734458029149,
     'lng': -118.2509807197085},
    'southwest': {'lat': 34.0446466197085, 'lng': -118.2536786802915}}},
  'place_id': 'ChIJh_dVskrGwoARddqbvhmoZfg',
  'plus_code': {'compound_code': '2PWX+93 Los Angeles, California, United States',
   'global_code': '85632PWX+93'},
  'types': ['street_address']}]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of `geocode_result` ?

Comment: Updated with geocode_reusult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some data in from `geocode_result`

**Use**

```
def geocode_results_process(x):
    lat_long_list = []         
    for item in x:
        for sub_item in item:
            list_component = sub_item['geometry']['location']
            latlong = str(list_component['lat']) + ',' + str(list_component['lng'])
            lat_long_list.append(latlong)
    return lat_long_list
```

Note:

- You can directly iterate your list and can skip `range` here.
- No need to iterate the dict. You can directly access the value using the key

Comment: This runs, but only returns a list of length 166

Comment: This works, great! I'm working on the exception clause now to continue when there is an empty value. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues with the code that you have written:

1. The `lat_long_list = []` should be inside the function definition.
2. you are running multiple for loops inside the function which is not necessary

With python, you can make the code much more readable by doing something like this:

```
def geocode_results_process(x):
    lat_long_list = []
    for list_item in x:
        for item in list_item:
            latitude= item['geometry']['location']['lat']
            longitude = item['geometry']['location']['lat']
            lat_long_list.append("{},{}".format(latitude, longitude))
```

I would recommend reading this https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-unpack-list-tuple-or-dictionary-to-function-arguments-using/ to get started with unpacking lists in python

Comment: This returns an error: ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: It was missing the second layer of for-loop. corrected it now